# Random connection timeouts only to one server

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, putty

I'm having a very strange issue with my connection to my server. Before you say "It's the servers connection" I know for a fact that it isn't, as other people are able to connect fine.

Basically, I keep getting random "lag" or delay from my server, mainly over PuTTY. It won't timeout, but it will take very long to respond. After that, it will be super-fast as it should, for a while, then it will randomly delay again. I am unsure what the cause is, it is ONLY to this server. Connections to other things are perfectly fine. The only other applications I have open are Skype (not in call) and TeamSpeak(no one speaking).

I am connected over WiFi with 4/5bar signal, SpeedTest:

[image]

Any advice or anything would be great, it's extremely annoying losing connection when I'm trying to work with things over SSH.

Comment: Before we start throwing out answers, what have you tried already?

Comment: I've searched for these sorts of issues with my ISP, and tried those solutions (settings in the router/modem hub). I've used TCPOptimiser, Default settings, aswell as "optimal" I've used CCleaner to remove cache like DNS cache etc and i also put my DNS servers back to default (I was using google's DNS servers). All of which made no difference.